# Trying to use for loop to shorten js but getting "not defined" error

Tags: javascript, for-loop, undefined

I'm a beginner in javascript and I'm trying to improve this: (which has been tested and works fine)

```
// snail 1  //
var s1 = document.createElement("div");
s1.id = snail1.id;
s1.className = "snail-container";
s1.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.snail1.photo+ "')";
s1.style.top = snail1.y + "px";
s1.style.left = snail1.x + "px";
racetrack.appendChild(s1);

// snail 2  //
var s2 = document.createElement("div");
s2.id = snail2.id;
s2.className = "snail-container";
s2.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.snail2.foto + "')";
s2.style.top = snail2.y + "px";
s2.style.left = snail2.x + "px";
racetrack.appendChild(s2);
```

...
...
...

and so on... (4 in total)

to a for loop that can do as many as I need but it says: Uncaught ReferenceError: snail is not defined
    at window.onload (race4.js:138) when I try this code:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
    var s1 = document.createElement("div");
    s1.id = snail+i.id;
    s1.className = "snail-container";
    s1.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.snail.photo+ "')";
    s1.style.top = snail+i.y + "px";
    s1.style.left = snail+i.x + "px";
    racetrack.appendChild(s1);

    }
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is `snail`? An object? Array?

Comment: `s1.id = document.getElementById('snail'+i).id`;

Comment: Hi KHS, it seems you're trying to dynamically fetch `snail[number].id` by using `snail+i.id`. This will be executed like: `(snail)+(i.id)` and since `i` is just a number, you can't call `.id` on it.

Comment: May I suggest you create an object called `snails` with following keys: `var snails = {'1': 'whatever snail 1 is', '2': 'whatever snail 2 is'}` and using `s1.id = snails[i]` instead? Make sure to replace `whatever snail 1/2 is` etcetera with the proper data though.

Comment: Using ABGR's solution my code now works and your explanation helped me understand why, so thanks SidOfc :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a problem with `snail+i.x`, correct it to `this["snail"+i].x` (so that you could access `snail1`, `snail2` etc) and similarly for others everywhere like this:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
    {
    var s1 = document.createElement("div");
    s1.id = this["snail"+i].id;
    s1.className = "snail-container";
    s1.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + this.snail.photo+ "')";
    s1.style.top = this["snail"+i].y + "px";
    s1.style.left = this["snail"+i].x + "px";
    racetrack.appendChild(s1);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should utilize an `array` or a `object literal` to keep a list of your snails and store their properties, then iterate through that to create those elements.

Here's one way you could go about this:

```js
var racetrack = document.getElementById("racetrack");

// create a "map" of all snails and their properties
var snails = {
  "1": {
    id: 1,
    photo:
      "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-illustration-snail-cartoon-260nw-187683554.jpg",
    y: 10,
    x: 10
  },
  "2": {
    id: 2,
    photo:
      "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-illustration-snail-cartoon-260nw-187683554.jpg",
    y: 20,
    x: 20
  },
  "3": {
    id: 3,
    photo:
      "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-illustration-snail-cartoon-260nw-187683554.jpg",
    y: 30,
    x: 30
  },
  "4": {
    id: 4,
    photo:
      "https://image.shutterstock.com/image-vector/vector-illustration-snail-cartoon-260nw-187683554.jpg",
    y: 40,
    x: 40
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(snails).length; i++) {
  var s = document.createElement("div");
  var snail = snails[i + 1]; // get snail's properties from the "map"

  s.id = snail.id;
  s.className = "snail-container";
  s.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + snail.photo + "')";
  s.style.top = snail.y + "px";
  s.style.left = snail.x + "px";

  racetrack.appendChild(s);
}
```

```css
.snail-container {
  width: 130px;
  height: 95px;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="racetrack"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you goto1 for taking the time to write all that code for me. Your solution also works brilliantly but I am currently practicing object oriented javascript where I am using a javascript class constructor to "create" the snails :)